# Filtering JSON data by date in R - Error: "comparison (5) is possible only for atomic and list types"

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to filter a weather dataset by year (I only want the data for 2021).

My code is:

```
library("rjson")
library('RJSONIO')
library(jsonlite)
library('tidyverse')

weatherraw <- fromJSON("my_weather_data.json" )

weather <- filter(date >= as.Date("2012-01-01") & date <= as.Date("2021-12-31"))
```

(The date column is originally in chr form)

I am getting error: `` Error in `>=.default`(date, as.Date("2012-01-01")) :  comparison (5) is possible only for atomic and list types ``

How to resolve this?

[snapshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i99Tp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed myself with

```
#change date format first using mutuate
df <- weatherraw %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")) 

#then filter
df <- subset(df, date> "2012-01-01" & date < "2021-12-31")
```